# Adding unity-dock shortcuts at static place

Tags: unity, unity-dash, shortcuts, dock

I would like to add a shortcut in my Unity Dock (the left panel), but right on top of the trash icon, in the "static" zone of the dock.

A picture is worth a thousand words :

[image: unity dock custom shortcuts]

Can you help me achieve that ? Thank you !

Comment: I don't think it's possible now. You can request it as a feature on Unity's Launchpad page, but I also doubt they'll implement it. But thumbs up for really nicely explained question. :)